# Round number in php depending on the value

Tags: php

I know the following code will remove the numbers are the point.
round($number);

I want to round the numbers as follows
if number is 20.123
I want result 20,
If number is 20.567
I want result 21

Means if value is below .5 , it should remove that value.
If value if .5 or above it should round up.
How  ?
Anyone help ?

Comment: use `ceil` and `floor` by checking the digit after the `.`.

Comment: Use round it will give you exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Round will do exactly that. https://3v4l.org/kP5Pf

Comment: Round will do what you want http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Round is just that: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_math_round

Comment: Everything that is wrong with Stack Overflow in three lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round($number)` will do what you want:

```
round(20.156); // 20
round(20.651); // 21
```

[Live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/903d120795c44a6f585d3a636b862a742ef411d4)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

use the `ceil`, `floor`, `explode` and `substr` function to achieve you value.

```
$num = "20.123";
$arr = explode(".", $num);

if(substr($arr[1], 0, 1) >= 5){
    $num = ceil($num);
}else{
    $num = floor($num);
}
echo $num;
```

**Result:**

> 20

Also you can use the `round` function.

```
round(20.156); // 20
round(20.651); // 21
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it's working well.

```
<?php
$var = 22.443;
$var = number_format($var, 0, '.', ''); 
echo $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_decimal_num($number){
    $num = explode('.', $number);
    return $num[1];
}
$num = 10.5 ; // for example

$val = get_decimal_num($num);

if($val >= 5)
{
  $value = (int) $num;
  echo $value = $value + 1;
}
if($val < 5)
{
  echo $num;
}

Plese check it...
```